# How to install and Configure Ubuntu One

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one, system-requirements

I have several Windows, Mac and Linux computers (No servers) and want to install Ubuntu One on them to share and save information. So my question is:

1. In what operating systems can I actually install Ubuntu One?
2. What are the requirements for it?
3. How to install and configure it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the comments:

## Ubuntu One's cloud storage was discontinued in 2014

---

### In what operating systems can I actually install Ubuntu One?

Ubuntu One is available in

- Ubuntu
- Windows (Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7)
- Mac (Mac OSX 10.6 and higher)
- Android (Android 2.1 and higher)
- Iphone (iPhone & iPad iOS 3.1 and higher)

Indeed, you can install Ubuntu One as a program on non-Ubuntu computers. Once you have an Ubuntu One account, you can actually `access your data`, `manage folders` and `upload files` on the web interface (which does not require any install): https://one.ubuntu.com.

### What are the requirements for it?

The requirements are essentially fairly basic. You need to have a supported operating system. You also need to install it with administrator right (on windows, for instance). No extra software is needed to run Ubuntu.

### How to install and configure it?

For setup instructions, read the (nice-and-easy) manuals for

- [Windows](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows/install/)
- [Ubuntu 12.04](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-one-on-ubuntu-1204-lts/), [Ubuntu 11.10](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-one-on-ubuntu-1110/), [Ubuntu 10.04](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-one-on-ubuntu-1004-lts/)
- [Mac](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-set-up-ubuntu-one-for-mac-279/)
- [Kubuntu](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-set-up-ubuntu-one-on-kubuntu/)

Configuring Ubuntu One often comprises of two steps.

Signing in with your account (or creating one if you have none).

[image]

Selecting the folder you actually want to synchronize. Note that the Ubuntu One folder (which is added to your home directory or your *My Documents* folder, for instance) is always synced.

[image]

Then you can just enjoy. More information can be found in the [FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/).

---

**Note** : Ubuntu One is a tool to synchronize information. It is a cloud service to synchronize information between 'computers.' Synchronizing is not the same as making a backup. Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) for backup tools. Your information in Ubuntu One still needs to be backed up.

---

Comment: Links above are broken.

Comment: Ubuntu One's cloud storage was discontinued in 2014.

Comment: Fair point, @EarthToAccess. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Note: Ubuntu One was discontinued in 2014. More information at

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One

### What is Ubuntu One?

Ubuntu One is the personal cloud that brings your digital life together, so you can enjoy your content, your way, wherever you are. With our suite of cloud services including storage, sync, sharing and streaming - you have immediate access to your music collection, favorite photos, videos, important documents and more, at any time and from any device.

### In what Operating Systems can I install Ubuntu One?

You can install Ubuntu One in [Windows, Mac, Android, IPhone, Ipad and of course, Ubuntu](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/).

You can download the version for your operating system directly from the Ubuntu One site:

- [Windows](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows/)
- [Mac](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/mac/)
- [Ubuntu](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/ubuntu/)
- [Iphone / Ipad](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/iphone/)
- [Android](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/android/)

### What are the Ubuntu One System Requirements?

The system requirements are very low. The space needed to install depends on the operating system but overall is less than **30 MB**. Regarding CPU or RAM it also depends on the operating system but on Ubuntu it uses less than **32 MB** and has less than 1% CPU usage when using an Intel Pentium 4 or above. Since Ubuntu One is a cloud service, it needs an internet connection to work correctly.

### How can I install and configure Ubuntu One

In the following link you will find up to date information regarding Ubuntu One's installation and configuration: [Ubuntu One FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/)

Some of the information in the FAQ covers:

- Installation on all operating system where it can be installed (Mac, Android, Windows)
- Configuration issues that the user might encounter.
- Installation on different Ubuntu versions
- Account Creation and configuration
- Account Issues
- File Syncing
- Sharing
- FTP Usage
- Music Streaming
- More...

Comment: Links above are broken.

Comment: Hi @gerard, Ubuntu one was deprecated 5 years ago.